# Kivy not working (Error: Unable to find any valuable Window provider.)

Tags: python, kivy

I have been getting this error: Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
With kivy heres the "full" error:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Victor\.kivy\logs\kivy_17-
05-27_10.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 17:54:52) [MSC 
v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil, img_gif 
(img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be 
found.
File "C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 
59, in core_select_lib
fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
File "C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\lib\site-
packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 26, in <module>
from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.dpi2px'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\lib\site-packages\kivy\utils.py", line 496, in __get__
 retval = self.func(inst)
 File "C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\lib\site-packages\kivy\metrics.py", line 174, in dpi
 EventLoop.ensure_window()
 File "C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 127, in ensure_window
 sys.exit(1)
 SystemExit: 1
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

thats the error and heres the code:

```
import kivy #added this just in case
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
       return Label(text="Hello World!!!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   SimpleKivy().run()
```

Can someone explain this error

Comment: Btw  i have downloaded pygame.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You're probably missing some dependencies. From the [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#installation):

> Install the dependencies (skip gstreamer (~120MB) if not needed, see
> Kivy’s dependencies):
>
> `python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew;`
>
> `python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer`

To install these dependencies, open up a terminal (can be a console, Pycharm Terminal window, etc.), run the first command and then the second command.

Answer (score 8):

The solution above did not work for me. Here is what I had to do to solve the problem on my Windows 10 pc with Anaconda Python 3.6 installed:

- open an Anaconda prompt window as administrator
- pip uninstall kivy
- pip install kivy
- pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2
- pip install kivy.deps.glew

Answer (score 7):

Even i have faced same problem.

Now it is working with conda install

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install kivy
```

Comment: After trying all the other solutions, this was the unique way to solve the problem on Windows 10, Anaconda3, Python 3.7 ... Thanks a lot ! Here are my commands: PS C:\Anaconda3> ./python.exe -m pip uninstall kivy

PS C:\Anaconda3> cd condabin
PS C:\Anaconda3\condabin> ./conda.bat config --add channels conda-forge
PS C:\Anaconda3\condabin> ./conda.bat install kivy==1.10.1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I tried many suggested solutions in vain. It only worked when I uninstalled and reinstalled kivy.

To uninstall:

```
    $ pip uninstall kivy
```

To install:

```
    $ python -m pip install kivy==2.0.0rc1
```

Answer (score -3):

try to disable the 3D and the 2D video acceleration acceleration in the (>>display>> settings ) of the virtual software (aka vmbox, vmware).