# I cant get the Kivy "Hello World" example to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pip, kivy

For some reson I just cant seem to get the Kivy ["Hello world"](https://kivy.org/#home) to work.

I have spent hours researching this online and have looked at all the related questions I could find here on Stack Overflow.

I have deleted and re-installed both kivy and python.

I have installed all of kivys dependencies and also pillow.

If it makes a difference I'm using python 3.

This is my Code.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

This is the response i get.

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Luc\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-03-25_6.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\Luc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\Luc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 26, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
 Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.dpi2px'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Luc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\kivy\utils.py", line 496, in __get__
     retval = self.func(inst)
   File "C:\Users\Luc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\kivy\metrics.py", line 174, in dpi
     EventLoop.ensure_window()
   File "C:\Users\Luc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\kivy\base.py", line 127, in ensure_window
     sys.exit(1)
 SystemExit: 1
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you install kivy according to the instructions [here](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html)?

Comment: Yes, I did install all of those.

Comment: Are you getting the SDL2 error when running the kivy app from PyCharm?

Comment: Yes, I was using PyCharm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219563/kivy-not-working-error-unable-to-find-any-valuable-window-provider) answer. It appears you need `kivy.deps.sdl2`.

Comment: Then, install all dependencies as described in the answer.

Comment: I have all those as well.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest uninstalling python(if its possible) and kivy and reinstall using [Anaconda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/windows.html). I have all packages installed through `conda` and don't get any issues at all. Although, you will still have to run `pip install kivy` as `conda` repos don't have this module. But Anaconda will take care of the imports and `PATH`. This Kivy program works perfectly for me. I used to have similar troubles with standalone Python and packages.

Comment: Okay, will do. I'll let you know what happens.