# Using Kivy in Visual Studio: Unable to find any valuable Window provider

Tags: python, visual-studio, kivy

I've installed all the dependencies, and uninstalled not-used python versions, but it still doesn't work. Does anybody know why? It's driving me crazy.

I'm using Python 3.7 (for 64-bit) and Kivy 1.11.1.

This is the complete log:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\svetz\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-12-20_11.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.1.17
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.1.9
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.1.12
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.1.22
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\svetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\svetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.5.0 - Build 25.20.100.6472'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 5
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.50 - Build 25.20.100.6472'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[WARNING] [Image       ] Unable to load image <C:\Users\svetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\data\glsl\default.png>
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - Exception: SDL2: Unable to load image
  File "C:\Users\svetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 71, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "C:\Users\svetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 152, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "C:\Users\svetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 981, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "C:\Users\svetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 312, in create_window
    super(WindowSDL, self).create_window()
  File "C:\Users\svetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1258, in create_window
    self.render_context = RenderContext()
  File "kivy\graphics\instructions.pyx", line 783, in kivy.graphics.instructions.RenderContext.__init__
  File "C:\Users\svetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 561, in __init__
    self.filename = arg
  File "C:\Users\svetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 756, in _set_filename
    mipmap=self._mipmap, nocache=self._nocache)
  File "C:\Users\svetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 460, in load
    im = loader(filename, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\svetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 223, in __init__
    self._data = self.load(filename)
  File "C:\Users\svetz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\img_sdl2.py", line 47, in load
    raise Exception('SDL2: Unable to load image')

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Comment: I just tried PyCharm but the same error occurred...

Comment: Looks like same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219563/kivy-not-working-error-unable-to-find-any-valuable-window-provider

Comment: @PabloGod No it isn't, the errors suggested by the logs are different.