# How to correct mistake in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

ver python-3.7.6
error

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\use53\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-01-07_9.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\use53\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 01:54:44) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\use53\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Analysing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed:
  File "C:\Users\use53\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\use53\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

I already reinstalled kivy several times but however gives out this error
Started on behalf of administrator did not help to eat for whom ideas that to do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kivy not working (Error: Unable to find any valuable Window provider.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219563/kivy-not-working-error-unable-to-find-any-valuable-window-provider)

Comment: @Zydnar not alone from answers me did not help 
kivy.deps.glew  "kivy.deps.glew" is not internal or external by a command executable the program or package file.

Comment: @orlatym the commands are: `python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2kivy.deps.glew` and `python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer`

Comment: @eyllanesc ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy.deps.sdl2kivy.deps.glew (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy.deps.sdl2kivy.deps.glew

Comment: Do this on the top of the file you're running
`from kivy.config import Config
Config.set("kivy", "log_level", "debug")
`
@or latym