# exe generated in pyinstaller using python & kivy is not working

Tags: python, kivy, exe, pyinstaller

I am very new to python programming. I have coded an app and it is running well in pycharm, but when I extracted the exe it is not working. Please help me out..

```
swscale-5.dll dependency of C:\Users\Muskaan Group\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ffpyplayer\tools.cp37-win32.pyd
107035 WARNING: lib not found: postproc-55.dll dependency of C:\Users\Muskaan Group\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ffpyplayer\tools.cp37-win32.pyd
107052 WARNING: lib not found: avdevice-58.dll dependency of C:\Users\Muskaan Group\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ffpyplayer\tools.cp37-win32.pyd
107133 WARNING: lib not found: swscale-5.dll dependency of C:\Users\Muskaan Group\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ffpyplayer\player\player.cp37-win32.pyd
107133 WARNING: lib not found: postproc-55.dll dependency of C:\Users\Muskaan Group\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ffpyplayer\player\player.cp37-win32.pyd
107149 WARNING: lib not found: avdevice-58.dll dependency of C:\Users\Muskaan Group\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ffpyplayer\player\player.cp37-win32.pyd
107406 WARNING: lib not found: swscale-5.dll dependency of C:\Users\Muskaan Group\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ffpyplayer\pic.cp37-win32.pyd
107421 WARNING: lib not found: postproc-55.dll dependency of C:\Users\Muskaan Group\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ffpyplayer\pic.cp37-win32.pyd
107446 WARNING: lib not found: avdevice-58.dll dependency of C:\Users\Muskaan Group\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ffpyplayer\pic.cp37-win32.pyd
```

Observed the above errors while the exe is being created but finally it said that the exe is created successfully.
I tried to find the error message at least, but the window closed so soon. Tried to open through command prompt and [here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9abI.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing some dependencies. From the docs:

Install the dependencies (skip gstreamer (~120MB) if not needed, see Kivy’s dependencies):

```
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew; 

python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
```

To install these dependencies, open up a terminal (can be a console, Pycharm Terminal window, etc.), run the first command and then the second command.

***and also make sure that defualt.png is available and loaded properly.***

similar thread:[Kivy not working (Error: Unable to find any valuable Window provider.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219563/kivy-not-working-error-unable-to-find-any-valuable-window-provider)