# How do I fix this issue? (kivy python, kivy 2.0.0)

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I keep running in into this issue, can you guys help please

[image]

Comment: Maybe this question could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219563/kivy-not-working-error-unable-to-find-any-valuable-window-provider

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Please also read [ask] and make sure that you show the information needed to answer the question. In particular, we can only help you fix problems with code that you actually show to us.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
    #Try this one .
    Python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew; 
    
    python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer

#Or You can also use this one solution.
pip uninstall kivy
pip install kivy
pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2
pip install kivy.deps.glew
```