# how to run a kivy app on ASUS tinker board?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to run a kivy app (basic to print hello world) on asus tinker board and i am facing this error.
I am new to the kivy app development as well as new working with the Asus tinker board.
Python version 3.7.3, pip version 22.0.4.

[error which i am facing while running a kivy app]

[image: 1]

Comment: Hi! Do any of the answers in this question help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219563/kivy-not-working-error-unable-to-find-any-valuable-window-provider

Comment: sadly, None of them works in my case.